# Redirect to another page in reactjs not working

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I'm trying to redirect to another page in a success scenario for my reactjs project. I have tried the ways explained in the following methods to do this but was not successful

```
this.props.router.push('/home');

this.context.router.push('/home');

this.history.pushState(null, 'home');

browserHistory.push('/home');
```

and many other ways i found on stackoverflow. How can i successfully do this.

My code

```
function handleLoginResponse(response){

    switch (response.data.response){

        case "200":
            /**
             * in sccuess senario
             * redirect to the home page
             * set cookies for token and user id create session
             * */

            this.history.pushState(null, 'home');


            break;
        case "201":
            console.log("201");
            break;
        case "202":
            console.log("202");
            break;
        case "203":
            console.log("203");
            break;
        case "204":
            console.log("204");
            break;
        case "205":
            console.log("205");
            break;
        case "206":
            console.log("206");
            break;

    }

}
```

I want to redirect to another page when i get a response of '200'

Thank you.

Comment: what's you Rout component look like?

Comment: which version of react-router you are using?

Answer (score 1):

with the simple way you can use Redirect

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
```

create state then connect the Redirect to your state

Example:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

export default class MyRedirect extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      redirect : false
    }
  }

  handleLoginResponse(){
    switch(response){
      case '200':
        this.setState({redirect: true})
      break;
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      {this.state.redirect && <Redirect to="yourpath" />}
    )
  }
}
```